# data not showing with sno

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with two columns `sno` and `userid`

What I want is that when a record with the same `userid` is inserted into the table then `sno` increases (like for first record *1* and second record *2*).

If a record with new `userid` inserts then `sno` starts from first (like for first record *1* and second record *2*)

Kindly help me.....

Comment: your question is not clear. Please format it and ask clearly.

Comment: How this is supposed to behave in case of rollback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get what you're asking for:

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (SNO, USERID)
  VALUES ((SELECT NVL(MAX(SNO)+1, 1)
             FROM SOME_TABLE
             WHERE USERID = &userid),
          &userid);
```

where `&userid` is your USERID value.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/699414/1)

Comment: How does that behave in case of concurrent inserts ? In that case, can't we have both inner queries returning the same `MAX()` ?